# Object reference to itself

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not sure how to state this question correctly, but I am trying to create a javascript object which handles an array of images so that they can be reordered/moved around.

```
function imgHandler(divname) {
    this.imgDiv = divname;
    this.img = Array("bigoldlizard.png","scarytiger.gif");
    this.update = function() {
        var htmlstr = "";
        for(i=0; i<this.img.length; i++) {

//This is the line in question:
        htmlstr += "<img src=\"" + this.img[i] + "\" onclick=\"javascript:" + ??? + ".remove(" + i + ")\"/></span>";

        }
        $("#" + this.imgDiv).html(htmlstr);
    }

    //remove an image from the array
    this.remove = function(index) {
        if (index >= 0 && index < this.img.length) {
            this.img.splice(index, 1);
            this.update();
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

So basically, I need the object to be able to add its own name, or be able to reference itsself...

Comment: Post some HTML and what you're actually expecting from your code specifically. Either that or you could take a look at JQuery UI's [Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/) plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create elements instead of HTML code, and create a closure to preserve the variables in the loop iteration, then the event handler code can use the variables:

```
  this.update = function() {
    var i, img;
    for(i=0; i<this.img.length; i++) {

      // closure for "this" and "i"
      (function(t, i){

        img = $('<img/>', { src: this.img[i] }).click(function(){
          t.remove(i);
        });

      })(this, i);

      $("#" + this.imgDiv).append(img);
    }
  }
```

Comment: This closure is by far the cleanest solution.

Comment: Either that or use event data.

Comment: can you elaborate on what using event data means?

Comment: I guess this was the best answer but I just went with the jquery sortable plugin mentioned above. JQuery is amazing.

Answer (score 0):

Guffa's solution may suffice, but it's typically not a good idea to create closures within loops. I've got a different approach that doesn't require much code refactoring on your part and provides a reusable component albeit with a bit more code:

```
// CALLBACK MANAGER MODULE BEGIN
// Create a manager for creating callbacks.
var callbackManager = (function () {
    var win = window,
        random = Math.random,
        // Create a hash for us to save all callbacks on.
        callbacks = {},
        // Generates the next unique ID for a callback.
        nextId = (function () {
            var next = 1;

            return function () {
                var n = next;
                next += 1;
                return n;
            };
        }()),
        // Generates the next valid callback name.
        nextCallbackName = function (prefix) {
            prefix = prefix || "___callback";
            return prefix + nextId(); 
        };

    // Save our hash of callbacks on the window object
    // so we can get access to the callbacks globally.
    win.callbacks = callbacks;

    return {
        // Creates a callback that will call the specified 
        // method on the 'thisObj'. Can specify optional arguments 
        // to have passed to the method call:
        //
        // callbackManager.makeMethodCallCallback(myObj, "welcome", "Alex");
        //
        // The callback will be returned and saved so it can 
        // be accessed globally.
        //
        // Each callback will be a function with the following methods:
        // getPath - Get the exported (i.e. global) path of the callback.
        // dispose - Disposes the callback by nulling out all references
        //      and removing it from global access.
        //
        // makeCallback(thisObj, methodName, ...)
        makeMethodCallCallback: function (thisObj, methodName) {
            var name = nextCallbackName(),
                args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2),
                callback = function () {
                    if (thisObj && 
                        typeof thisObj[methodName] === "function") {
                        return thisObj[methodName].apply(thisObj, args);
                    }
                };

            callback.getPath = function () {
                return "window.callbacks." + name;
            };
            callback.dispose = function () {
                thisObj = null;
                callback = null;
                args = [];
                delete callbacks[name];
            };

            return callback;
        };
    };
}());
// CALLBACK MANAGER MODULE END

function imgHandler(divname) {
    this.imgDiv = divname;
    this.img = Array("bigoldlizard.png","scarytiger.gif");
    // Define an array of callbacks.
    var callbacks = [];

    this.update = function() {
        var htmlstr = "",
            // Declare a local variable for a callback.
            callback;

        for(i=0; i<this.img.length; i++) {

        // Create a new callback and save it so we can dispose it when
        // this image is removed. We also pass the index of the image.
        callback = callbackManager.makeMethodCallCallback(this, "remove", i);
        callbacks.push(callback);
        // All callbacks have a getPath() method that will return
        // the callback's exported (i.e. global) path, such as "window.callbacks.__callback92".
        htmlstr += '<img src="' + this.img[i] + '" onclick="' + callback.getPath() + '(); return false;/></span>';

        }
        $("#" + this.imgDiv).html(htmlstr);
    }

    //remove an image from the array
    this.remove = function(index) {
        if (index >= 0 && index < this.img.length) {
            this.img.splice(index, 1);
            this.update();

            // Dispose the callback associated to this image
            // then tombstone it so that the order other callbacks
            // will be maintained.
            if (callbacks[index]) {
                callbacks[index].dispose();
                // Tombstone the callback.
                callbacks[index] = undefined;
            }

            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Guffa's technique and this one should do the trick though.

EDIT:
I hadn't realized that you are using jQuery. I'd recommend using jQuery's `click()` event-helper rather than the `onclick` attribute if you can. Perhaps try to combine my `callbackManager` and Guffa's approach could offer the best of both worlds; creating `<img>` elements and using jQuery's `click()` helper and using a reusable callback manager module.